# Have Chrome/Safari changed the way they treat image loading using as3?

Tags: flash, firefox, google-chrome, actionscript, safari

I'd like to start off by saying I've never posted in a forum like this, so if I violate any conventions or porotocols, please be patient and correct me.

The Problem:

I created my site using Flash and AS3. You can see it at www.the-ruck.us
I was checking it the other day, and noticed that the slideshow that's supposed to start once you hit "enter" doesn't start anymore, but just stays a blank white page.

This behavior only occurs in Chrome and Safari. Firefox still works fine. Another interesting symptom: it only happens on the "live" version of my site. When I open an offline version on my computer, using both Chrome and Safari, it works fine.

The images are loaded from a separate folder, using an XML file for reference.

Here's my code:

```
//these functions load/parse the XML file
function LoadXML(e:Event) {
    slideshowXML = new XML(e.target.content);
    parse(slideshowXML);
}

function parse(ssXML:XML) { 
    wallpaperLinks = slideshowXML.img.attributes(); 
    paperCounter = randomNumber();
}

//a function to fade each successive image in
function fadeIn(e:Event) { 
    if (!isPaused) ticker.start();
    ssLoader.loaderMask.scaleX = 0;
    TweenMax.from(e.target.content, fadeTime, {alpha:0, ease:Quint.easeOut, onComplete:killKid});
    TweenMax.to(ssLoader.loaderMask, fadeTime, {scaleX:1, ease:Quint.easeOut});
}

//loads the first slide in the slideshow
function loadFirstPaper() {
    removeChild(bloomer);
    ticker.stop();
    newPaper = new ImageLoader(wallpaperLinks[paperCounter], {container:wallpaper, onComplete:fadeIn, autoDispose:true, dispose:true});
    newPaper.load();
}

//function that loads each successive slide
function changePaper(e:Event) {
    ticker.stop();
    paperCounter = randomNumber();
    newPaper = new ImageLoader(wallpaperLinks[paperCounter], {container:wallpaper, onComplete:fadeIn, autoDispose:true});
    newPaper.load();
```

}

```
//cleanup function
function killKid() {
    if(currPaper is DisplayObject) wallpaper.removeChildAt(1);
    currPaper = newPaper.content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got this error while loading your website.

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at mysite_fla::MainTimeline/loadFirstPaper()
    at Function/http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::apply()
    at com.greensock.core::TweenCore/complete()
    at com.greensock::TweenMax/complete()
    at com.greensock::TweenMax/renderTime()
    at com.greensock.core::SimpleTimeline/renderTime()
    at com.greensock::TweenLite$/updateAll()
```

So I guess you should investigate this error and it'll solve your problem. I guess either `ticker` or `wallpaperLinks` is null.

Comment: Thank you for the help! How did you generate that error? Because I can't seem to reproduce it.

Also, any idea why this only happens in Chrome and Safari, while it works fine in Firefox? The other strange thing is that I haven't changed anything about my page since I put it up, and it suddenly stopped working out of the blue.